# how to make restrictions in php?

Tags: database-design, normalization

I have a mini enrollment system.

there are tables for professors, subjects, students, grades, and subjects that has students.

now, when you add a professor, you input it's professor ID. but there is aslo a profNO. and the profNo is the primary key. since you can add more subjects to that professor, the profNo will increment but the ID stays the same.

PROBLEM: now, I want to set a restriction that when one wants to add a professor, if he inputs a professor ID that already exists, an error would appear which says "professor ID already exists" but the professor ID is not unique.

now, take a look at the photo. there are same professor IDs with different profNo. and that is because of the subjects they have. professor IDs were duplicated when you add subject to a professor. but when you add a professor, could it be possible that when one inputs an existing ID, an error would appear?
[sample http://sphotos-e.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/578472_162759700529875_718824031_n.jpg](http://sphotos-e.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/578472_162759700529875_718824031_n.jpg)

Comment: This is not necessarily PHP related, are you using a DBMS - Any SQL, etc.?

Comment: If ID is not unique and you want to show an error when one exists, how will you ever add more than 1 ID?

Comment: You want an error if it already exists, but you don't want it to be `UNIQUE`? This seems like a contradiction. Can you explain your situation a bit more?

Comment: Also, if profNo is the primary key, should you really be incrementing it for any given professor?

Comment: There is missing data here. If there is a `Professor` table, it would not matter whether the subject table can have multiple (non-unique) Professor ID's. You should edit your question and provide complete information about the tables related and their connections.

Comment: now, take a look at the photo. there are professor IDs with different profNo. and that is because of the subjects they have. professor IDs were duplicated when you add subject to a professor. but when you add a professor, could it be possible that when one inputs an existing ID, an error would appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do what you're asking. Just add a simple check before you insert new professors.

Pseudocode for when a new professor is submitted:

```
if profID already exists (using a simple SQL query to check)
    allow the insert and continue
else
    don't insert, show a message to the user "That professor ID already exists"
endif
```

However, it doesn't seem like a very logical system if you are duplicating professor details over and over when a professor has multiple subjects.

Consider this DB structure:

**Table: `professors`**

Fields: `id`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`gender`

**Table: `subjects`**

Fields: `id`,`professorid`,`subjectname`,`subjectcode`

With that, you would only maintain a single record in `professors` for each professor and the same for the subjects table. When you insert new subjects, you would populate the professor ID which links back to the `professors` table without duplicating data.

This would be a simple structure that makes your database much more efficient, now depending on how complex your system needs to be you may need to normalise it even further. For example, if a subject can have multiple professors then you would not include a professor ID in the subject table, instead you would have a new table `professor_subject_association` with fields `professorid`, `subjectid` where you would link multiple professors to subjects.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `ID` column have a **UNIQUE INDEX**. Read about those on the MySQL manual: **[Creating Indexes on MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)**